# Unit root tests for panel data in R

Tags: r, panel-data, unit-root

I have the `plm` package and would like to run unit root tests on some variables. I get the following error:

```
> purtest(data$tot.emp)
Error in data.frame(baldwin = c(59870, 61259, 60397, 58919, 57856, 57227,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 14, 19, 11, 12, 1, 20, 18, 10, 13
```

I assume that I'm getting this error because my panel is unbalanced. Two questions:

- Can you use panel unit root tests (Levin, Lin and Chu (2002), Im, Pesaran and Shin (2003), or others) for unbalanced panels?
- If so, is it implemented in R?

Comment: I can't answer your question but FYI, Stata runs these tests even when the variable is unbalanced. However, Breitung's, Harris-Tzavalis and Hadri's LM tests seem to require balancedness.

Comment: An update. Take a look at the punitroots package. I think it may do what you want. http://road.unimol.it/bitstream/2192/163/3/ESDP11063.pdf

Comment: The issue of unbalanced panel data is addressed in version 2.2-2 of plm on CRAN. The tests of Hadri and of Levin/Lin/Chu are not applicable to unbalanced data, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the current moment (version 1.2-10, 2012-05-05) it seems that the unbalanced case is not supported. **Edit:** The issue of unbalanced panel data is solved in version 2.2-2 of plm on CRAN (2020-02-21).

Rest of the answer is assuming version 1.2-10:

I've looked at the code, and the final data preparation line (no matter what is your initial argument) is the following:

```
 object <- as.data.frame(split(object, id))
```

If you pass unbalanced panel, this line will make it balanced by repeating the same values. If your unbalanced panel has time series with lengths which divide each other then even no error message is produced. Here is the example from purtest page:

```
 > data(Grunfeld)
 > purtest(inv ~ 1, data = Grunfeld, index = "firm", pmax = 4, test = "madwu")

Maddala-Wu Unit-Root Test (ex. var. : Individual Intercepts )

  data:  inv ~ 1 
  chisq = 47.5818, df = 20, p-value = 0.0004868
  alternative hypothesis: stationarity
```

This panel is balanced:

```
 > unique(table(Grunfeld$firm))
  [1] 20
```

Disbalance it:

```
 > gr <- subset(Grunfeld, !(firm %in% c(3,4,5) & year <1945))
```

Two different time series length in the panel:

```
 > unique(table(gr$firm))
  [1] 20 10
```

No error message:

```
> purtest(inv ~ 1, data = gr, index = "firm", pmax = 4, test = "madwu")
 
    Maddala-Wu Unit-Root Test (ex. var. : Individual Intercepts )

data:  inv ~ 1 
chisq = 86.2132, df = 20, p-value = 3.379e-10
alternative hypothesis: stationarity
```

Another disbalanced panel:

```
  > gr <- subset(Grunfeld, !(firm %in% c(3,4,5) & year <1940))
  > unique(table(gr$firm))
  [1] 20 15
```

And the error message:

```
 > purtest(inv ~ 1, data = gr, index = "firm", pmax = 4, test = "madwu")
  Erreur dans data.frame(`1` = c(317.6, 391.8, 410.6, 257.7, 330.8, 461.2,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 15
```

Comment: The issue of unbalanced panel data is addressed in version 2.2-2 of plm on CRAN. The tests of Hadri and of Levin/Lin/Chu are not applicable to unbalanced data, though.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to convert your data to `pdata.frame`? I have an unbalanced panel also, but `purtest` seems to work with unbalanced panel if the data is `pdata.frame`. But I might be wrong too:)

However in `?purtest` authors write:

```
"object, x  

Either a 'data.frame' or a matrix containing the time series, 
a 'pseries' object, a formula, or the name of a column of a 'data.frame',
or a **'pdata.frame'**
on which the test has to be computed; a'purtest' object for the print 
and summary methods,"
```

So I guess if one uses `pdata.frame` the `purtest` "understands" that panel is `unbalanced`.

Am I wrong???

Comment: I tried but this does not work for me.

Comment: The issue of unbalanced panel data is addressed in version 2.2-2 of plm on CRAN. The tests of Hadri and of Levin/Lin/Chu are not applicable to unbalanced data, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for sure the IPS test on unbalanced data, as long as you test for the Wtbar or Ztbar statistic.

Fore example, the following R code can be used to test sattionarity in unbalanced heterogeneous panel data, with IPS test (plm package):

```
`purtest(data$tot.emp, test = c("ips"), ips.stat="Ztbar", exo="intercept",dfcor=TRUE, lags = c("AIC"), pmax = 10)`
```

Answer (score -1):

`Eviews 5` allows you to test the `panel unit roots` for the `unbalanced` data that is not possible with `R` and `Stata`. For example, even though `Im–Pesaran–Shin` and `Fisher-type` tests can be applied for unbalanced panel in `Stata`, it is not possible if we have some observations , with the gap i.e. we have data of country i for year 2002 and 2004 but not 2003 (assuming the lag to be greater than one). I think that `Eviews` drop all such observations while performing tests, for our example this is country i. However, if you manually drop all such observations, you can still perform the tests with `R` and `Stata.`