# R: Calculating Unit Root for unbalanced data with gaps

Tags: r, panel-data, unit-root, plm

I have panel [data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/femodel_root_test.csv) that I need to calculate a unit-root test on. The data is unbalanced and has gaps. Does anyone know of a library that handles unbalanced panel-data with gaps? I have tried the `purtest` command from the R package `plm` but it does not handle unbalanced panel data as has been documented [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33364/unit-root-tests-for-panel-data-in-r/44179#44179).

Comment: The issue of unbalanced panel data has been addressed with version 2.2-1 of plm. The tests of Hadri and of Levin/Lin/Chu are not applicable to unbalanced data, though.